# How to avoid overwriting the previous data using excel4node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, excel4node

I have some data and I am storing it in excel csv, using npm package excel4node. But as I run the script a new instance of workbook is created. If I am running the script multiple times I want to keep on appending the new data in the sheet rather than creating a new instance of the workbook.

```
var workbook = new excel.Workbook();
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("sheet1");

for (var i = 1; i < allTexts.length + 1; i++) {

  worksheet.cell(i + 1, 1).string(allTexts[count]);
  worksheet.cell(i + 1, 3).string(allnumbers[count]);
  count++;
}

workbook.write("sample.csv");
```

Comment: Have you got the solution? If yes please post here.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there are any append methods in the docs. A workaround might be to use a different package to convert it to JSON first and then just add the data and export it as a new csv. I prefer to use [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)